# Entity Framework: nullable DateTime toString(format) in vb.net handling

Tags: vb.net, datetime, entity-framework-4.1

Given a table Element with a DateTime field birthday (not null), in Entity framework 4 I am allowed to do:

```
Dim mylist = (From el in Element Select el).ToList()
     .Select(function(el) new with { 
           .bday = el.birthday.toString("dd/MM/yy") 
           }
```

I am now required to change birthday to be nullable, therefore I change the table in SQL server and then update my ModelDB in Visual studio.
The result is that the line:

```
           .bday = el.birthday.toString("dd/MM/yy")
```

raises an exception as "Invalid cast from integer to string "dd/mm/yy").
The only way to get it "fixed" is to change the line this way:

```
           .bday = CDate(el.birthday).toString("dd/MM/yy")
```

Is this the correct approach?
Now that I have a nullable Datetime, how to handle the case when el.birthday is null?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do a small experiment, you would understand perfectly what is happening:

```
Dim normalDate As Date = Now
Dim nullableDate As Nullable(Of Date) = normalDate

Dim normalToText As String = normalDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy") 'Works perfectly

Dim nullableToText As String = nullableDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy") 'Error
```

The content in both variables, `normalDate` and `nullableDate`, is identical but they are not: the `ToString("date in certain format")` functionality expects a `Date` type as input; what you are sending is a modified version of the Date type (not too different, but not the same either). With `CDate` what you are doing is converting the modified version of Date into an actually valid Date type and thus the ToString() functionality works without any problem.

Are you doing the right thing? Yes, as far as CDate can deal with "nulls" (`CDate(Nothing)` does not output any error): you are adapting the given variable to what ToString() expects.

NOTE: I have checked the exact error output by the code above and it effectively delivers a "Conversion from string "dd/MM/yy" to type 'Integer' is not valid.". Thus the error you are getting is the standard error when intending to use ToString("date") with a Nullable Date; not too descriptive error, this is true.

Comment: Actually I am unable to understand why the error is somehow related to an Integer, since in the DB the field is Datetime (never change this). Anyway, I got an error when CDate(el.birthday) is called on a el.birthday null element, but I will write a few lines of code to solve this..

Comment: @Desmond I have updated my answer right now: if you put a try... catch surrounding Dim nullableToText As String = nullableDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy"), you would see that the error you get is the one you report. The error is not too descriptive but is the standard one when using this method with nullable dates, thus nothing wrong with your input data.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with nullable properties, the db column is mapped to System.Nullable(Of T) ([See Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)). So in your case, the `el.birthday` should have been mapped to `Nullable(Of DateTime)`. This class has two properties to deal with the situation you have, that are, `.Value` ([Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.value?view=netframework-4.7.2)) and `.HasValue` ([Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.hasvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

The actual type specific value is stored in `.Value` so in your case, you need to do something like this:

```
.bday = el.birthday.value.toString("dd/MM/yy")
```

Or you can use `.HasValue` which returns boolean to indicate if there is a value:

```
If el.birthday.HasValue Then
   .bday = el.birthday.toString("dd/MM/yy") 
End If
```